# Preventing from Deleting a Row

Tags: c#, if-statement

I just created a `DataGridView` and a delete button that deletes a row. However, I accidentally clicked the delete button, even though there's no data inserted. Application break mode appears. What I did is I created a If-else statement to prevent that from happening. But I can't get it right.

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.RowCount. = 0)
    {
       MessageBox.Show("Nothing to Delete");
       return;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete the selected items?", "Students_Records", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);
        studentsBindingSource.RemoveCurrent();
    }
}
```

I always get this error:

> CS1001    Identifier expected

Note: I'm a newbie

Comment: Welcome to [so], please tag the programming language, and try to point which line have the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a full stop where you shouldn't:

```
if (dataGridView1.RowCount.=0)
```

should be:

```
if (dataGridView1.Rowcount == 0)
```

You'll also need the double == to test the value; a single = will try to assign the value.